# Root Samsung Galaxy S3 with broken USB port

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.4-kitkat, usb, root-access

I recently purchased a Sprint Galaxy s3 on ebay with a broken charge port, and have revived it with a wireless charging reciever and charger. I want to root it but there is no way to connect it to my computer. i have looked into the framaroot/one click root but am unsure how reliable it is and my firmware version is 4.4.2 so it is probably not an option anyway(as it doesn't support higher than 4.2)

Is there a way to do this? could i possibly connect my s3 wirelessly to my computer? I want to root my s3 but am stuck with no idea. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [towelroot](https://towelroot.com/), which should support all phones < jun 3 2014